# how to make background-image on html

Tags: html, css

I am currently using a template and there some code I don't understand

```
<div class="item owl-bg-img" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1050');">
```

I don't want to mess up with CSS and I just want to change the code in HTML as you can see it is linked to online but I want to link to my local computer. i have html and all css and the picture but dont know how to link

Comment: background: url('file:///C:/Users/userid/desktop/f/pic.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

You cans simply change this 
`background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1050');` as per your requirements.
If you want to add image background then  replace  `http://placehold.it/1920x1050` with your actual image path.
If you want to use color background then remove `background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1050');` and use `background: red;` Add your color or color code instead of `red`

Answer (score 0):

To link to an image in your PC, you need to have the HTML file in your PC and to link the image location to the one on your PC. Example:
Let's say you have index.html and background.jpg in the same folder, then you use:

```
<div class="item owl-bg-img" style="background: url(/background.jpg);">
```

You can do the same by using CSS.

```
.item owl-bg-img { 
  background: url(/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

Assign the background to the entire HTML using CSS

```
html { 
  background: url(/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

Use the IMG tag. It is hard to set a background image to a DIV, it is also not recommended.

```
<img class="item owl-bg-img" src="/background.jpg">
```

Then you just add the CSS (width, height, etc) to the class "item owl-bg-img" like you would do to a DIV.

Another way if you really need that DIV,

```
<div class="item owl-bg-img"><img src="/background.jpg"></div>
```

This way the DIV will be the size of your image, otherwise resizing the DIV using CSS, will scale the IMG tag to fit the DIVs size.

Comment: That means there is something wrong with the other parts of your HTML code because what I put above is from my website and it works 100%

Comment: If you want to set a background to the entire HTML, why you don't assign it to the entire HTML rather than to a DIV?

Comment: i just want the picture for slider on home page not entire html

Comment: Then why don't you use the <img> tag? It is hard to set a background image to a DIV, it is also not recommended.
`<img class="item owl-bg-img" src="/background.jpg">`

Then you just add the CSS (width, height, etc) to the class "item owl-bg-img" like you would do to a DIV.

Comment: Then you could have multiple <img> tags in a single <div>. Easier to sort things and position them.

Comment: Another way if you really need that DIV,
`<div class="item owl-bg-img"><img src="/background.jpg"></div>`

This way the DIV will be the size of your image, otherwise resizing the DIV using CSS, will scale the IMG tag to fit the DIVs size.

Comment: i use template and when i change to <img> tag i crush

Comment: cant is use div for img src

Comment: You can check it as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: yeah the only problem was /background.jpg i change it just background.jpg and it worked :)

Comment: Usually on a webhost (linux) it should have worked like "/background.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, you need to download the image you want to link to your local machine and then reference that in your background-image inline CSS.

Have a look at this link hopefully, it helps.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: yeah, that's what i said up there i dont want to change the css but html

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS may be simpler than you think. Try adding this in the `<head>` and `</head>` tag of your HTML page:

```
<style>
  .banner {background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1920x1050")}
</style>
```

And then put this where you want your image to show:

```
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Style as needed, add text, etc.

If you want to host the file on your own machine, simply replace "http://placehold.it/1920x1050" with something like "assets/pics/my_image.jpg".

Good luck!